# Shift n letters in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve an udacity programming question which is as folows:

> Write a procedure, shift_n_letters which takes as its input a lowercase letter, a-z, and an integer n, and returns the letter n steps in the
>   alphabet after it. Note that 'a' follows 'z', and that n can be positive, negative or zero.

**Code:**

```
def shift_n_letters(letter, n):
  result = chr(ord(letter) + n)
  if ord(result) > 122:
    return chr(96+ ord(result) - 122) 
return result


print shift_n_letters('s', 1)
#>>> t
print shift_n_letters('s', 2)
#>>> u
print shift_n_letters('s', 10)
#>>> c
print shift_n_letters('a', -1)
#>>> z
```

I am getting `t, u , c` and ` as the results. Please can someone help where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: use [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take `n` to the modulus of the length of the alphabet:

```
def shift_n_letters(letter, n):
    n_ = n % 26
    result = chr(ord(letter) + n_)
    if ord(result) > 122:
        result = chr(ord(result) - 26) 
    return result
```

It's messing up because (i think) its using the order of letters in the unicode system, where apparently ` comes before *a.*

### Update

I came up with a much simpler algorithm.

```
def shift_n_letters(letter, n):
    return chr((ord(letter) - 97 + n % 26) % 26 + 97)
```

#### Algorithm

1. `ord(letter) - 97`   -- Put `letter` in the range 0-25 by subracting the unicode order of *a*
2. `+ n % 26` --  Add the shift, adjusted for period boundary between *z* and *a*
3. `% 26` --  Take modulus 26 in case the shift caused the order to leave the range 0-25
4. `+ 97` --  Add the unicode order of *a* (which was previously subtracted)
5. `chr(...)` -- Return the character of the unicode order index that we just computed

Comment: It's typically a bad idea to change the value of a variable like that. I'd recommend changing `n` to something else when you set it equal to `n%26`

Comment: @Signal why is it a bad idea? If the variable is passed to the function overwriting stays within the scope of the function, and since it's a small function and n only has one use, what harm is done? I realize problems with readability may occur in larger scopes, but would PEP8 even complain? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: AFAIK it does *not* violate PEP 8, but for the reasons you've already mentioned it is a good practice.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your comment I updated the answer :)

Comment: This works well but I don't really get it. I'd really like to understand how this works, how would I go about that would you suggest? thanks

Comment: @Scriptable Letters a-z are between the 97'th and 122'th items in the Unicode alphabet. `n` could be any crazy big number but because the a-z alphabet has periodic boundaries you just take the `% 26` to `n` because moving 145 or 15 characters ahead makes no difference. Then you get the unicode alphabet order of `letter` and add to it `_n` but if that gives you a character that is out of the a-z range (`ord(result) > 122`) you remove an alphabet length of indexes from `result`. I updated the code a little to make it simpler to understand.

Comment: Why is it necessary to take modulus 26 twice?

Comment: @EllenSpertus Good catch. One can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks. Can step three be removed?

Comment: @EllenSpertus Either 2 or 3

Answer (score 2):

Use `maketrans` to avoid all the hassle involved with `chr` or `ord`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans):

> *string.maketrans(from, to)*
>
> Return a translation table suitable for passing to translate(), that will map each character in *from* into the character at the same position in *to*; *from* and *to* must have the same length.

Example for your use case:

```
import string

def shift_n_letters(text, n):
    intab = string.ascii_lowercase # "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    outtab = intab[n % 26:] + intab[:n % 26] # alphabet shifted by n
    trantab = string.maketrans(intab, outtab) # translation made b/w patterns

    return text.translate(trantab) # text is shifted to right
```

How it works in practice:

```
>>> shift_n_letters('a',-1)
'z'
>>> shift_n_letters('s',10)
'c' 
>>> shift_n_letters('hello',10)
'rovvy'
```

This has the advantage of working with more complex strings than just single characters and can work for any `n`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with the wrong codes for letters

```
def shift_n_letters(letter, n):
  result = ord(letter) + n
  while result > ord('z'):
    result -= 26
  while result < ord('a'):
    result += 26 
  return chr(result)
```

or (more succint, but with a little more arithmetic--modulo arithmetic)

```
def shift_n_letters(letter, n):
  result = ( ord(letter) + n - ord('a') ) % 26
  return chr( ord('a') + result )
```

both will work for any value of `n`

Answer (score 1):

You need to take n modulo 26, written n%26, where you currently just have n: result = chr(ord(letter) + n%26).That way you wrap around correctly instead of going through the rest of the unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
def shift_n_letters(letter, n):

    # Create an array of characters from 'a' to 'z'
    char_array = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)] 

    result = ""
    for ch in list(message):
        # Get the corresponding index in char_array and add 'n' to it. 
        # Also remember to % 26, which is length of char_array
        index = (char_array.index(ch) + n) % 26

        # And append to result string the newly computed character 
        result += char_array[index]

    return result
```

Hope that helps.